# Mongoid: Get users that are missing documents of at least one category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I'm using Ruby On Rails with Mongoid for the ORM.

I have a `User` class and a `Document` class. User has_many documents. A Document has a category.
There are multiple categories, but some of them are mandatory.

I want to retrieve all users that are :

- missing a Document in one of the mandatory categories
- or users who do not have documents at all

Here's what I've tried so far with aggregates, but this does not work :

```rb
def self.without_all_required_documents
  subquery = Document.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" => { "user_id" => { "$ne" => nil }, "category" => { "$in" => required_categories } } },
    { "$group" => { "_id" => "$user_id", "categories" => { "$addToSet" => "$category" } } },
    { "$project" => { "_id" => 1, "missing_categories" => { "$setDifference" => [required_categories, "$categories"] } } },
    { "$match" => { "missing_categories" => { "$ne" => [] } } },
    { "$project" => { "_id" => 1 } }
  ])

  where(
    :"$or" => [
      { :id.in => subquery.map { |doc| doc["_id"] } },
      { :"$and" => required_categories.map { |cat| { :"documents.category" => cat } } },
      { :"$expr" => { :"$eq" => [{ :"$size" => { :"$ifNull" => ["$documents", []] } }, 0] } }
    ]
  )
end
```

I get records that have documents, records that have all required documents, and no records that do not have documents.

Comment: Please provide sample documents and the requested result for them

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all users that are missing a document in one of the mandatory categories or users who do not have documents at all, you can use the following query:

```
User.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "documents",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user_id",
      "as": "documents"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "$and": [
            { "documents.category": { "$in": ["mandatory_category1", "mandatory_category2"] } },
            { "documents": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "category": "mandatory_category1" } } } },
            { "documents": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "category": "mandatory_category2" } } } }
          ]
        },
        { "documents": { "$size": 0 } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Here's how it works:

- The $lookup stage performs a left outer join on the documents collection using the user_id field as the foreign key.
- The $match stage filters the results based on two conditions:

  - The $or operator combines two conditions:

    - The first condition selects users who have at least one document in one of the mandatory categories, but missing at least one of them.
    - The second condition selects users who do not have any documents.
  - The first condition is specified with an $and operator, which includes three sub-conditions:

    - The first sub-condition selects documents that have a category in the mandatory categories list.
    - The second and third sub-conditions use the $not operator and $elemMatch to select documents that do not have a specific category.
  - The second condition selects users who have an empty documents array.

Note that you need to replace "mandatory_category1" and "mandatory_category2" with the actual names of your mandatory categories.